# Densest hydrogen storage medium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, materials, hydrogen

What compounds or nanostructures contain the most hydrogen atoms per unit of volume in realistic conditions (under 1 GPa). Particularly boron-free compounds because it's to be used in sci-fi nuclear designs.

---

What I've investigated so far:

- Zirconium Tetrahydride (0.229 mol/ml, unstable?)
- Thorium tetrahydride?
- Ammonium Borohydride (~0.176 mol/ml, unstable?)
- Aluminum Borohydride (~0.175 mol/ml)
- Borazane (0.152 mol/ml)
- Aluminum Hydride (0.148 mol/ml)
- Tetramethylammonium Borohydride (0.146 mol/ml)
- Solid Ammonia (0.144 mol/ml)
- Solid Hydrazine (0.143 mol/ml)
- Uranium Hydride (0.136 mol/ml)
- Paraffin Wax (0.131 mol/ml)
- Liquid Cyclopropane (0.128 mol/ml)
- Tetramethylammonium Chloride (0.128 mol/ml)
- Beryllium Borohydride (0.125 mol/ml)
- Lithium Borohydride (0.122 mol/ml)
- Liquid Ammonia (0.120 mol/ml)
- Beryllium hydride (0.118 mol/ml)
- Sodium Borohydride (0.113 mol/ml)
- Magnesium hydride (0.112 mol/ml)
- Water (0.111 mol/ml)
- Cyclohexane (0.111 mol/ml)
- Neopentyl alcohol (0.111 mol/ml)
- liquid ethane (0.109 mol/ml)
- ammonium fluoride (0.109 mol/ml)
- Hexane (0.106 mol/ml)
- Neopentane (0.104 mol/ml)
- liquid methane (0.105 mol/ml)
- ethanol (0.103 mol/ml)
- liquid cubane (0.099 mol/ml)
- lithium hydride (0.098 mol/ml)
- lithium aluminum hydride (0.097 mol/ml)
- liquid propane (0.091 mol/ml)
- Solid hydrogen (0.087 mol/ml)
- Liquid hydrogen (0.070 mol/ml)

Comment: Just my two cents.
I guess you already looked these compounds up, but in "Sustainable Energy Systems and Applications", 2011, is written:

"The ammonia-boron compound with chemical formula NH4BH4 appears to be the most “dense” hydrogen storage. "

Comment: Zirconium hydride (e.g. $\ce{ZrH}$ or $\ce{ZrH_{1.65}}$, but not $\ce{ZrH4}$) is actually used in some nuclear reactors because of its unusual moderating properties.

Comment: As an aside, if you're looking for non-chemisorbed (i.e. the $\ce{H/H2}$ is not bonded to the material), Metal-Organic Frameworks (MOFs) have some of the highest uptakes of the gas -- achieving near-liquid density. NOTT-112 gets ~0.058mol/mL at 77K/60atm if you count the H in the MOF. Obviously not even comparable to bonded H.

Comment: Interesting article about storage in palladium http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v13/n8/full/nmat4030.html?foxtrotcallback=true

Comment: Since it's sf, maybe you can imagine someone figured out a way to keep muons from decaying, in which case muonic H atoms have a radius 200x smaller than regular H atoms, so muonic H2 ought to be about 10^7 times denser than ordinary H2.

Comment: Er...but I believe this brings the nuclei so close that there is a reasonable probability of fusion under ordinary conditions, because the one nucleus can tunnel into the other, which could quite mess up the integrity of your storage vessel.

Comment: indeed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon-catalyzed_fusion