# What is the liquid which has the most hydrogen atoms per volume?

Tags: stoichiometry

What is the liquid which has the most hydrogen atoms per volume at STP ?
Is there anything better than water?

[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117073/most-dense-hydrogen-containing-composition) does not answer this question because none of the compounds listed in it are liquids at STP, which contain more hydrogen per volume than water.

Comment: Hydrazine is slightly better.

Comment: How about liquefied methane?

Comment: Methane is not a liquid at STP.  Without this temperature and pressure restriction, the liquid Hydrogen would beat them all ;)

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson you are right

Comment: No, that's wrong. Liquid methane contains more hydrogen per volume than liquid hydrogen itself.

Comment: @ Ivan: At all pressures and temperatures where both are liquid ?

Comment: @George: there are ***no*** such conditions where both are liquid simultaneously.

Comment: Hydrogen atoms tend to get fluffy in elemental H2.  Covalent bonds with other elements or incorporation into an ionic lattice strongly favors squeezing down the hydrogen atoms, allowing higher hydrogen density even with the other element taking up space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most dense hydrogen containing composition](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117073/most-dense-hydrogen-containing-composition)

Comment: @ Matthew. No, that question and answer is not about liquids at STP.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67681/densest-hydrogen-storage-medium

Comment: That's too broad. Even among pure compounds there's many "better" then water, for example cyclodecane. There's no telling what's "the best" and with mixtures complexity is tremendous.

Comment: What is too broad?  Cyclodecane has a 1:2 ratio of Carbon to Hydrogen and it has a density of 0.871 g/ml.  That is a better mass ratio than the 1:2 ratio of Oxygen to Hydrogen and the density of 1.0 g/ml for water.

Comment: What mixture can beat Cyclodecane ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hydrazine has more hydrogen atoms per mL than water**

Some simple calculations give the moles of hydrogen per mL in some possible alternative liquids. Taking into account density and molecular mass we get the following results:

Water 0.056 mol/mL 2 Hydrogens -> 0.11 mol H/mL
Hydrazine 0.0313 mol/mL 4 hydrogens -> 0.125 mol H/mL

symmetric dimethylhydrazine 0.0138 mol/mL 8 hydrogens -> 0.111 mol H/mL
methyl hydrazine 0.0191 mol/mL 6 hydrogens -> 0.115 mol H/mL

So, while some other liquid at STP hydrazine derivatives beat water, it looks like hydrazine has notably more hydrogens per unit volume. This is probably the record.

Answer (score 0):

Some *solid* metal hydrides have more hydrogen per unit volume than either liquid or solid hydrogen.  They are candidates for storage in hydrogen-fueled processes.  A few examples of such metal hydrides are given [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/117106/17175).

Comment: Are they liquid at STP ?

Comment: Did I not qualify the answer by identifying these materials as _solid_?

Comment: Did I not qualify the question by asking for identification of materials that are liquid at STP ?  Your answer refers to solid materials, thus it is off-topic.